# Code coverage not happening while writing unit test case to the promise function

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I am writing unit test cases by using angular 6 and jasmine. I am unable to cover the **getUserJSON** function after writing small test case on the below code function. How to cover hole function to get full percentage in **code coverage** for this function.

```
export class UserLoginService implements OnDestroy {



  // Store the userdata
  getUserDatafromSubject(userData: IUser) {
    this.userData.next(userData);
  }

  //To get LoggedIn User Deatils
  getUserJSON(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
      this._servSub = this.http.get<IUser>(/*environment.appBaseUrl + 'Account/LogIn' */'api/homepage/user.json').subscribe(value => {
        value.selAssetClass = 'COM';
        if (!value.userId || !value.userName || value.userAsset.length === 0 || value.pageAccess.length === 0) {
          value.isAuthorized = false;
        } else {
          value.isAuthorized = true;
        }
        this.getUserDatafromSubject(value);
        resolve(true);
      })
    });
  }
```

And my spec file is as follows:

```
import { TestBed, inject, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { UserLoginService } from './user-login.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';


describe('UserLoginService', () => {
  let service: UserLoginService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [UserLoginService],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    });

    service = TestBed.get(UserLoginService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });



  it('should call getUserJSON from apiService', function(done) {
    spyOn(service, 'getUserJSON').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
    service.getUserJSON()
      .then((result) => {     
        expect(result).toEqual(true);
        expect(service.getUserJSON).toHaveBeenCalled();             
        done();
      });
  });

});
```

My test case is passing fine but unable to cover code fully. I want to cover *getUserJSON* function fully. any help?

Comment: Why are you spying if call function in the next line?
If you want to spy, spy the http call or give it proper values which should a resolve or a reject in two test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are spying on `getUserJSON` and returning a value. When you do this, the actual function is never executed, instead the spy is getting called. This is why you don't see the coverage.

To call the actual `getUserJSON` function and still spy it, replace your `spyOn` call with the below code:

```
spyOn(service, 'getUserJSON').and.callThrough();
```